# How to remove a defective wine application that refuses to uninstall?

Tags: wine, software-installation, uninstall

I attempted to install a windows application (DaemonLite) via Wine. Halfway through, a message came up that because of some "serious problem" it was not possible to install the program. Yet the program showed up in the Wine uninstaller. When I tried to unistall the program from the Wine uninstaller, I got the message that it was not possible to uninstall the program! I then uninstalled Wine altogether and re-installed it. Even then the defective program (together with the others that are working fine) showed up and refused to uninstall. So I am now stuck with a faulty program that neither works nor  uninstalls. Can anyone suggest a way out of the mess?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this will be to open nautilus, (the program where you view your files), go to your home directory, and press Ctrl + H. This will show hidden files, and you can double-click on .wine to open it. Under .wine, there should be a folder called something similar to drive_c. If you click on that you will see program files, and program files should contain the folder you are looking for. You can then delete it.

I hope that helps.

To do this in the terminal, you would press Ctrl + Alt + T, and then enter the following:

```
ls -a "/home/<enter your username here>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files"
```

That will show you the list of directories in your program files. Choose the one you want to delete, and then type

```
sudo rm "/home/<enter your username here>/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/<enter name of folder to delete here>"
```

All commands in the terminal are case-sensitive, unless you specify otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, I am sure I am making a mistake somewhere. Ctrl+H in Home directory brought up a series of folders and files, but no Wine, although Dash shows Wine is installed. And Terminal isn't accepting the other commands.

Comment: @user255726 - its a hidden folder in your home directory that looks like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/trTRE.png). Inside it is the folder 'drive_c', which acts like a Windows C: drive and where wine installs the files.

Comment: Yes, I have finally located it. All this while, strangely enough, the Home directory > Ctrl+H wasn't showing .wine, although it had been installed. It has come up now after restarting the computer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Wine has a 'C drive' of sorts in the directory `~/.wine` (a hidden file in your home directory), where it installs the Windows programs, and keeps its current configuration. So, you could reset wine by running this (it will remove all of wine's current configuration):

```
rm -r ~/.wine
```

Instead, you may just want to back it up so you can restore later if needed, by moving it:

```
mv ~/.wine ~/.winebackup
```

Another method would be search in `~/.wine` for the installed program and remove it - this is better if you have other stuff installed in wine you want to keep.

You run these commands in terminal - like this: 
[image]

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to ubuntu. How do I run these commands? Should I simply copy-paste them in Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)? Should they be preceded by "sudo apt-get" or not? I ask because a little while ago I tried to do something like this, but to no avail. And how do I go to the directory ~/.wine to search for the installed program?

Comment: This is what I did. But I have been getting the message:        rm: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

Comment: its a  [Tilde `~`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) not a `-`... ('Shift'+'#' on my keyboard). `rm -r ~/.wine`

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I'm sure I'm bothering you too much from my ignorance, but just one more clarification. Since the other method (searching directly in ~/ .wine) allows selective removal, it's attractive, and is easier too. But after locating the program how to remove it? Right-clicking the program name brings up no such option, but only "cut" and "move to trash". Surely I can't simply delete the folder containing the program, or can I?

Comment: @user255726 - you can move it to trash, go to trash and then delete it - or enable the delete option in Nautilus (file manager's) settings, and right-click and use Delete

Comment: Simply delete it? I mean it's probably OK to straightaway delete a program that hasn't installed properly. But in the case of an installed program isn't it necessary to first uninstall it from the Add/Remove dialogue and only then delete any residues  (as done in Windows)? Or is it that in Ubuntu one can just search out a program in Wine and delete it?